# Calling a function using a thread in C

Tags: multithreading, function

I have a very generic question. I want to create two threads and in one of he thread I want to do a function call to a particular function and get the value in he thread returned by the function.
I function calling possible in threads? I am not able to find a good example online if this is  possible. Else, if this cannot be achieved in C, then can I use a third thread to communicate to and from the second thread??Point me to a good tutorial in this regard if you can.

Thanks

Comment: Which OS threading library are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A thread is just a separate parallel execution flow through your program, that happens to operate in the same address space.  So yes, you can call a function in a thread.

If you specify a language, then perhaps I can point at an example.

Comment: Thanks! I could find details regarding this using C# Java etc but not C so was afraid that C does not provide that functionality

Comment: Could you give an example. That would be really helpful.

Comment: If you know how to start a thread, then there is nothing more to know regarding calling functions within a thread - it's exactly the same.  There are of course plenty of gotchas with threading to be aware of, but calling functions isn't one of them.

Comment: C itself has no such functions; you need support from whatever OS you're working on.  For instance, on Linux there is the [pthreads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthreads) library.  On Windows, there is [`CreateThread()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682516(v=vs.85).aspx) and related functions.